# Why does bng_latlon OSGB36toWGS84 give incorrect calculation result?

Tags: python, latitude-longitude

I installed the python package `bng_latlon`

```
pip install bng_latlon
```

then ran

```
from bng_latlon import OSGB36toWGS84

OSGB36toWGS84(352500.2, 401400)
```

The expect result should be  `(53.50713, -2.71766)`,
but I get `(54.754303, -0.001713)`.

for

```
OSGB36toWGS84(538890, 177320)
```

it gives (nan,nan) as result.

May I ask why this happen? I suspect this is to do with system setting, but I am not sure.

Comment: The results are close, I suspect it's related to floating point error. What system setting do you think could affect this?

Comment: Do you get the expected result if you try the example at https://pypi.org/project/bng-latlon/? `OSGB36toWGS84(538890, 177320) => (51.477795, -0.001402)`

Comment: I get the "expected result" of `(53.50713, -2.71766)` for `OSGB36toWGS84(352500.2, 401400)`, so something does seem to a amiss.

Comment: Hi Barmar, no, the result is (Nan,Nan). :(